# Google page speed insights and CLS

Tags: layout, shift, psi, cls

Under my field data overview, CLS value comes out to be 0.98
whereas when, I look at description for Avoid large layout shifts - CLS contribution is 0.004.

How to figure out the elements that are causing CLS?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shreya you need to use Chrome click on the 3 dots to the right then go to more tools then developers tools in the screen that appears click  on the performance tab click the dot to the left it will turn red when it recording when it finishes you get an orange bar that says Layout shift[image] double click on that bar and it should give you more infomation in the Summery tab in this example it gives the following

1. Layout Shift Warning Cumulative Layout Shifts can result in poor user
   experiences.
2. Score1.000
3. Cumulative Score1.000
4. Had recent input No
5. Moved fromLocation: [0,0], Size: [360x640]
6. Moved toLocation: [0,0], Size: [360x640]
7. Related Node li.velocity-animating::before